# Imaging Source Gige camera taking lots of memory for processing in Aravis

Tags: python, opencv

Imaging Source Gige camera is running continuously in my python code. Using software triggering. It gradually increasing memory for possessing and after sometime it stuck due to the low memory.

here is my python code for capture frame.

```
import cv2
from random import sample,randint
from aravis import Camera

cap = Camera("camera_1")
cap.cam.set_frame_rate(110)
cap.cam.set_exposure_time(1000)
cap.cam.set_trigger("Software")
cap.start_acquisition()

def GetVideo():
    cap.cam.software_trigger()
    camPhoto = cap.pop()
    return camPhoto
```

How i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wrapper library](https://github.com/oroulet/python-aravis) you seem to be using, suggest an [alternative method](https://github.com/oroulet/python-aravis/blob/master/aravis.py#L262) to capture frames (your `GetVideo` only takes single frames, it does NOT return a time-series of images, so it's a bit of a misnomer):

```
def get_frame(cam):
    cam.start_acquisition()
    frame = cam.pop_frame()
    cam.stop_acquisition()
    return frame
```

Remark that it starts and stops the acquisition each time. By inspecting the `stop_acquisition` method, you will notice that it redirects that call to the Aravis library, where most likely the memory buffers are correctly torn-down.

In your current implementation, you will probably notice that each time you call `GetVideo`, the memory increases by about the same amount as the size (in MB) of a single image. It is my guess that by using some of the more specific methods available to `cap.cam` (an instance of the `Aravis.Camera`), you will be able to set up a "ring" structure, which is typical for streaming video. However, if you just want snapshots, then use the code above.